# How do I separate results from a multi-geometry rioxarray clip opeartion?

Tags: python, raster, clip, rasterio, rioxarray

I have MODIS data .hdf format and multiple polygons representing regions of interest.

I can clip the raster using rioxarray such that

```
polygons = [polygon1, polygon2, polygon3, ... ]

with rioxarray.open_rasterio('MODIS_file.hdf') as src:
    clipped_result = src.rio.clip(polygons)
```

However, the clipped result is a single DataArray. Is there a way to have clip return a list of arrays that are the clipped result for each polygon passed to src.rio.clip? I have tried the individual approach

```
with rioxarray.open_rasterio('MODIS_file.hdf') as src:
    for polygon in polygons:
        clipped_result_for_one_polygon = src.rio.clip([polygon])
```

but the drop in speed of execution is significant, given that `len(polygons) > 1000`

Comment: You could try this: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html

Comment: @snowman2 Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.